# Relation between Code Length and Symbol Weight in a Huffman Code

Tags: it.information-theory

I'm not sure if I should ask this here or over at StackOverflow (sorry if this is not the right place).

I'm constructing a [Huffman code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_coding) for a series of symbols with associated weights. I have a list of the code-lengths corresponding to each symbol, sorted by symbol weight (in non-decreasing order). Does it follow that this list is also sorted by code-length (in non-increasing order)?

I suspect that the answer is yes (since lower-weighted symbols will generally have shorter code lengths), but I'm not sure if this is guaranteed.

I guess what I really want to know is, "if a Huffman tree has two leaves *a* and *b*, where *a* had a higher weight than *b*, is *b*'s code length always at least that of *a*'s?"

Thanks!

Comment: does "weight" in this case mean frequency ? the code length according to a huffman code is almost exactly $\log(1/p_i)$, where $p_i$ is the normalized frequency.

Comment: @Suresh: Yes, that's what I meant, sorry. How does one normalize a frequency? And why only "almost exactly"?

Comment: @Cameron: you normalize the frequency $f_i$ by dividing it by the sum $n$ of the frequencies, so that to get $p_i=g_i/n\in [0,1]$

Comment: One comment: the code length in a Huffman code is not necessarily "almost exactly $\log 1/p_i$", although it is generally within a constant factor.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. A Huffman code is optimal. If a less frequent symbol had a shorter code length than a more frequent symbol, then you could get a code with better performance by exchanging them.